# Why do we divide the expectation of the indicator function times X by P(B) for E[X|B]?

Tags: probability

Given the definition of conditional expectation as E$[X|B] = \frac{E[1(B) \cdot X]}{P(B)}$, and understanding $1(B)$ as an indicator function that returns $1 (0)$ when $B$ is true (false), it would seem $E[1(B)\cdot X]$ takes the expected value of members of $X$ where $B$ is true. Why the further division by $P(B)$? Intuitive as well as formal explanation requested.

E.g., suppose we have:

> $(S,P)$:
>   $(1,3)$
>   $(1,4)$
>   $(0,3)$
>   $(0,2)$
>   $(0,1)$
>   $(0,0)$
>   $(1,1)$
>   $(1,2)$
>   $(1,3)$
>   $(0,2)$

$P(S = 1) = 0.5$, $E[1(S=1) \cdot P] = \frac{13}{5} \approx 2.6 $ (where $1[x]$ is an indicator function that flips to $1$ if $S = 1$ and $0$ if $S != 1$).

Thus $E[P|S = 1] = \frac{E[1(S=1) \cdot P]}{P(S = 1)} \approx 5.2$? What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$E[1[S=1] P] = 13/10$, not $13/5$, assuming each possible outcome you listed has the same probability.

Comment: Ah, I see, I was throwing out the values for which 1[S = 1] = 0. Dumb mistake.